# How do I get the maximum within a subset of my dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, subset

How do I get the maximum within a subset of my dataframe in Pandas?

For example, when I do something like

```
statedata[statedata['state.region'] == 'Northeast'].ix[statedata['Murder'].idxmax()]
```

I get a KeyError that indicates that `idxmax` is returning the key for the global maximum, Alabama, rather than the maximum within the queried subset (from which that key is of course missing).

Is there a way to do this concisely on Pandas?

---

For reference, the data used here is from R, using

```
data(state)
statedata = cbind(data.frame(state.x77), state.abb, state.area, state.center, state.division, state.name, state.region)
```

then exported from R and imported by Pandas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [df.loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix) to select the sub-DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.rpy.common as com
import rpy2.robjects as ro

r = ro.r
statedata = r('''cbind(data.frame(state.x77), state.abb, state.area, state.center,
                 state.division, state.name, state.region)''')
df = com.convert_robj(statedata)
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().str.replace('state.', '')
subdf = df.loc[df['region']=='Northeast', 'Murder']
print(subdf)
# Connecticut       3.1
# Maine             2.7
# Massachusetts     3.3
# New Hampshire     3.3
# New Jersey        5.2
# New York         10.9
# Pennsylvania      6.1
# Rhode Island      2.4
# Vermont           5.5
# Name: Murder, dtype: float64
print(subdf.idxmax())
```

prints

```
New York
```

---

To select the state with the highest murder rate ([as of 1976](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/state.html)) for each region:

```
In [24]: df.groupby('region')['Murder'].idxmax()
Out[24]: 
region
North Central    Michigan
Northeast        New York
South             Alabama
West               Nevada
Name: Murder, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `com.load_data` do load all the extra data at once (rather than one `df['region'] = com.load_data('state.region')` for each column. And is there a better way to handle `'state.center'`, which has two columns?

Comment: I think in this case, it might be easier to use R syntax to form the R dataframe, and then use `com.convert_robj` to convert it to a Pandas DataFrame. I've update the code above to show how.

Comment: This might be a nice example for: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html